# why "throws exception" in java but not in c++?

Tags: java, c++

I'm learning to use java, I think I already know the basics of C++. But, as I just started learning java, the first bits of 'hello world' program I noticed uses 'throws exception' when initiating the main function in the main class. Why is it used? Do we do something similar in c++? Is returning 0 in int type main function in c++ a similar thing?

Comment: Read a tutorial about [**exceptions**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Comment: Because C++ exceptions are broken? Returning from main in C++ is the same as in C, it sets the return value of the program and exits.

Comment: What if an exception came before returning ? :)

Comment: an exception has nothing to do with the return type. It indicates that the method might throw an exception that must be catched in a higher function

Comment: C++ exceptions are not broken.

Comment: @Dan : "_Because C++ exceptions are broken?_"... That's a bold statement...

Comment: @Dan Just a mistaken one.  Like everything, they can be improved, but they're significantly better than exceptions in Java (which are arguably broken).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, specifying that a method`throws SomeException` means that any method calling that method will have to either catch or itself throw that exception. In the case of the main function, it just means that you don't have to catch any exceptions that may occur directly in the main method, they will instead be passed on to the underlying runtime, resulting in a stack trace print and program exit.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't, or at least, I've never seen a `main` in Java which
did it.  I'm not even sure that it's legal.  (Given the way Java
uses exceptions, it shouldn't be.  Only `RuntimeException` and
`Error` should propagate out of `main`.)

Java tends to overuse exceptions; especially, it uses exceptions
in cases where return values would be more appropriate (e.g.
things like not being able to open a file).  In a correct
program, these exceptions must be handled (just as in a correct
program, C++ returned error codes, or in the case of input and
output, the stream state, must be handled).  Java uses the
exception specifier to declare these exceptions (and only
these—it isn't necessary to declare things that would be
an exception in C++).

Comment: I've seen hundreds, and of course it's legal. Test programs abound in them.